# How to combine these two functions?

Tags: functions

[image]

I combined them as [image]

Is that correct?

Comment: $$\textbf{Yes!}$$

Comment: So by Vieta's formulas (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas), $m$ and $n$ will be the solutions for the equation $x^2-10x+6=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If we set $a+b=S$ and $ab=P$, then we have the following equation whose solutions are $a$ and $b$: $$X^2-SX+P=0$$. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Note that $m$ and $n$ are the solutions of the quadratic equation $x^2-(m+n)x+mn=0$ that is $x^2-10x+6=0$ and $x_{1,2}=5\pm\sqrt{19}$ and $x_1=m, \,x_2=n$.